# PHP выбрать из массива одинаковые значения

Tags: php, массивы

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [msisdn] => 79112221122 [called] => 7234346383 [dates] => 2018050108 [duration] => 13 ) 
[1] => Array ( [msisdn] => 79112221122 [called] => 78787878787 [dates] => 2018050108 [duration] => 142 )
)
```

Как вывести или собрать в новый массив те элементы, где $array['msisdn'] повторяется? 
Получается нужно взять каждое значение $array['msisdn'] и пройти по всему массиву, если значение найдено - записать в новый массив. Потом перейти к следующему значению $array['msisdn'] и повторить итерацию.

Comment: array_filter поможет, но мысль у вас верная.

Comment: Вот пытаюсь сообразить как callback функцию составить для него

Comment: А нужно вывести все ? Или только один? Если все, то проще отсортировать и вывести все.

Comment: Нужно вывести все повторяющиеся вместе с остальными элементами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение что называется "в лоб":

```
$array = [
    ['msisdn' => 79112221122, 'called' => 7234346383, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 13],
    ['msisdn' => 719112221122, 'called' => 78787878787, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 142],
    ['msisdn' => 79112221122, 'called' => 78787878787, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 142],
];

$buffer = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'msisdn'));
$buffer = array_filter($buffer, function($i){ return $i > 1; });
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    ! array_key_exists($item['msisdn'], $buffer) ?: $result[] = $item;
}

var_dump($result);
```

---

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'msisdn' => int 79112221122
      'called' => int 7234346383
      'dates' => int 2018050108
      'duration' => int 13
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'msisdn' => int 79112221122
      'called' => int 78787878787
      'dates' => int 2018050108
      'duration' => int 142
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно можно проще, но на быструю руку так:

[Здесь можно посмотреть результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc382d25c2cac82b5ea33596c7d82d9eb29ceae8)

```
<?php

function msisdn($el)
{
    return $el['msisdn'];
}

$array = Array ( 
0 => Array ( 'msisdn' => 79112221122, 'called' => 7234346383, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 13 ),
1 => Array ( 'msisdn' => 79112221122, 'called' => 78787878787, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 142 ),
2 => Array ( 'msisdn' => 719112221122, 'called' => 78787878787, 'dates' => 2018050108, 'duration' => 142 )
);


$ar_uniq = array_map('msisdn', $array);
$ar_uniq = array_unique($ar_uniq);

foreach( $ar_uniq as $key => $value ){
    $ms = $value;
    $new = array_filter( $array, function($ar) use ($ms)
                        {
                            foreach( $ar as $k => $v ){
                                return($v == $ms);
                            }
                        }
                );
    print_r($new);
}
```

Comment: А этот почему выводится у него вроде нет дубля 719112221122?

Comment: Это я добавил, чтобы выводил все уникальные значения. Если нужно чтобы выводило только те, которые имеют дубли, сделайте проверку `if count($new)>1`